# Вопрос новичка. Как вставить символ в input range?

Tags: javascript, input

Всем привет!

Как вставить символ в значение input range?
Как использовать js скрипт для двух инпутов?

Код https://jsfiddle.net/ecmm7mko/

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function() {
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue;
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);
body {
  font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}

.value {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed #bdc3c7;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
  text-shadow: white 2px 2px 2px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="value">0 Р</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
```

Благодарен за любую помощь или направление.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте его таким образом:

```
target.innerHTML = newValue+' P';
```

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

var rangeValue = function() {
  var newValue = elem.value;
  var target = document.querySelector('.value');
  target.innerHTML = newValue+' P';
}

elem.addEventListener("input", rangeValue);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:700);
body {
  font-family: "Dosis", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #34495e;
  padding-top: 40px;
  text-shadow: white 1px 1px 1px;
}

.value {
  border-bottom: 4px dashed #bdc3c7;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 60px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  letter-spacing: -0.07em;
  text-shadow: white 2px 2px 2px;
}

input[type="range"] {
  display: block;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:hover {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #e74c3c;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="value">0 Р</div>
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="1" value="0">
```

Comment: Это здорово! Спасибо за помощь! Вы не могли бы подсказать, как использовать это для нескольких инпутов на одной странице?

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers